# Нужно ли нижнее подчеркивании при именовании SCSS файлов?

Tags: scss, бэм

заметил, что в некоторых сборках люди именуют scss файлы таким образом __header.scss, а кто-то именует просто header.scss,   причем именование без нижнего подчеркивания задается при нахождение в отдельной папке,  где хранятся также pug и js файлы. С чем это связано?

Comment: кому как нравиться...

Comment: то есть при сборке в один глобальный scss файл это не повлияет?

Comment: нет..............